# JavaScript Method Not Called in Footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am using AngularJS includes. The code for my `index.html` is as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="">

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/application.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-include src="'../includes/footer.html'"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

`application.js` is in a folder called `js` and it reads as follows:

```js
function setFooter() {
    var currentDate = new Date();
    currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();
    document.write('&copy;&nbsp;' + currentYear + '&nbsp;All rights reserved.');
}
```

`footer.html` is in a folder called `includes` and it reads as follows:

```html
<div id="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="footerContainer">
            <p class="text-white">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    setFooter();
                </script>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

AngularJS includes are working since the footer is displayed in `index.html` but the JavaScript function `setFooter` in `footer.html` is never called.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you included application.js in the page?

Comment: are you seeing any errors in the console ?

Comment: ex: <script src="../js/application.js"></script>

Comment: You may want to read the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Comment: why you not want use angular for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-include` load html by AJAX, so any javascript tag not processed. Instead of using script and *document.write* directly, better use of angular functionality.

Simplest way, in my opinion, would be add simple controller, like

```
angular.module('app', [])
       .controller('footerCtrl', function($scope) {
           $scope.currentYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();
       });
```

and use it in footer

```
<div id="footer" ng-controller="footerCtrl")">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="footerContainer">
            <p class="text-white">
                &copy;&nbsp;{{ currentYear }}&nbsp;All rights reserved.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

also don't forget name your application in *index.html*

```
<html ng-app="app">
```

[**working plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/PNKfKBA4dHqLx7MsQAdG?p=preview):